# How to add a column in Unix

Tags: unix

Add a column before column n:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="fs"}{$n = value OFS $n}1' filename.
```

I have tried this command but it doesn't work. What does the "n" represent here? Do I have to change the n to a value?

All together I have a file with 17 columns. I would like to add a new column in between column 6 and 7.

Answer (score 1):

This is better achieved by looping on the field:

Input file:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17
```

Then adding "18" in between 6 and 7:

```
awk -F \| '{ for (i=1;i<=6;i++) { printf "%s ",$i } printf "%s","18";for (i=7;i<=$NF;i++) { printf " %s",$i } printf "\n" }' file
```

Explanation:

```
awk -F \| '{ 
        for (i=1;i<=6;i++) { 
             printf "%s ",$i # Loop through the first 6 space delimited fields and print with a space after each one to replicate the delimiter
        } 
        printf "%s","18"; # Print "18" with no spaces
        for (i=7;i<=NF;i++) { 
          printf " %s",$i # Loop through the rest of the field printing a space and then the field (NF - represent the last field)
        } 
        printf "\n" # Print a new line
      }' file
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 18 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17
```

Comment: I tried this coding but then the output is not as i expected.

Comment: originating 1|Originating 2|Originating C3|Originating 4|Originating 5|Sender6|Terminating 18 7|Terminating 8|Terminating 9|Terminating 10|Terminating 11|Recipient 12|Message 13 | Time 14|Time 15|Output 16|Content 17 18

Comment: You need to change the field separator using -F \|. I have amended the answer